# Why do some avatars have drop shadows?

Tags: discussion, style

I was looking at a [question today](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40263/figuring-the-svo-of-the-sentence-im-tom) and I noticed that the OP and I have drop shadows beneath out avatars and the person who edited the question and the other answerer do not.

Who gets a drop shadow, and why?

[image: avatar on right with drop shadow, avatar on left without]

[image: top avatar without shadow, bottom avatar with]

Comment: See

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work

For background -- this is new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The avatars with a drop shadow are avatars that show a popup when you hover your mouse over them.
For this to happens, the user must have entered something in the "About Me" field, and have a reputation higher than 1000. There could be a minimum length for the "About Me" description: When the length of the entered text doesn't reach that limit, the popup is not shown.

[image: screenshot]